# Dropdown with a search field

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I would like to build a dropdown box with a search option for all the elements in the list much like Google Analytics has.

To make it more clear, something that looks like this:
[image]
Would like to keep it as much html/css as possible but for as far I can see this there will be some javascript/jquery/wizardstuff needed ;)

Anyone knows where to start? a tutorial? an working example?

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you are looking for something like a dynamic search box, try looking for a function called autocomplete().
Try Visiting
http://www.java4s.com/jquery-tutorials/example-get-autocomplete-feature-in-javajsp-with-jquery-api/
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can investigate [existing plugins](http://www.sitepoint.com/16-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/). Also worth to look at [jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). And [here is some explanation how another jquery combobox works](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/a-jquery-ui-combobox-under-the-hood/).